# Mostrar datos por Ajax en WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, html5, ajax, wordpress

Hola he creado un plugin de wordpress que recoge datos de un formulario y mediante la clase $wpdb conecta y hace una consulta en la base de datos.

El problema que tengo es que el plugin me muestra esos datos en la parte superior izquierda de la pantalla y yo necesito que los muestre donde yo le diga (en un custom html que es donde tengo el formulario).

Y no se como hacerlo, lo mas que he logrado es dentro del plugin crear un archivo html donde le consigo pasar ese valor por medio de un include, y en el html lo paso a una variable en javaScript y lo muestro por un alert, pero lógicamente eso no me sirve.

Necesito ayuda para mostrarlo donde yo pido, he visto que con Ajax es posible hacer algo parecido pero no se como, no entiendo de ajax y me he visto par de paginas pero no me entero, si alguno me puede echar una mano lo agradeceria.

Codigo del plugin PHP:

```
 <?php
 $NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];
$ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];
global $wpdb;
$puntos = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT puntos FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" );

include 'template/mensaje.html';?>
```

Codigo del html:

```
<script>
var puntos = <?php echo $puntos;?>;
alert(puntos);
document.getElementById("puntos").innerHTML = puntos;
```

Codigo del Custom HTML(Formulario que recoge los datos y los manda al PHP para hacer la consulta):

```js
    var puntos = 58
    document.getElementById("puntos").innerHTML = puntos;
```

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="NumTarjetaFidelizacion" required="">
<input type="text" name="ClaveTarjeta" required="">
<input type="submit" value="Consultar" >
<p>Tu saldo es: </p><div id="puntos"></div>

</form>
```

El código básicamente ha de recoger los datos de un usuario y mostrar cuantos puntos lleva acumulados.

Comment: ¿El contenedor donde quieres que se muestre tiene el id `puntos` (ese id no debe estar repetido en ninguna parte del DOM)? ¿Cómo manejas la respuesta de Ajax?

Comment: Con Ajax no he echo nada todavia, he intentado que me muestre los datos pero no lo consigo y la verdad que ya me frustra un poco esto. he puesto el mismo nombre y en el contenedor no me muestra el dato pero si lo hace por el alert

Comment: Si muestra los datos en el alert debe mostrarlos en el contenedor también. ¿Cuál es el HTML donde dices que le pusiste el id `puntos` a un contenedor? ¿Ese contenedor es visible? ponle algo de texto manualmente para ver si se ve. ¿Confirmas que no hay nada más con  ese mismo id en el DOM? ¿Esto `document.getElementById("puntos").innerHTML = puntos;` está antes o después del formulario en la jerarquía del DOM?

Comment: Al ponerle texto manualmente si se ve, el problema viene que tengo que hacer la web con WordPress, y el formulario lo tengo en una pagina en un custom html, y no puedo referenciar el php al custom html, por lo que creo que es el motivo por el que no se muestra el codigo (he editado y puesto el codigo del formulario y del contenedor donde quiero que se muestre)

Comment: Yo no entiendo mucho lo que dices ni lo que quieres hacer realmente. Hablas de Ajax pero luego dices que no, que no estás usando Ajax. Hablas de un plugin y luego hablas de un custom.html, muestras un formulario, etc, etc. Lo que creo que te pasa es que tienes demasiado lío. No se entiende si quieres escribir un plugin el cual tenga un formulario que haga una búsqueda en el servidor y te traiga datos para mostrarlos en alguna parte. No se sabe si donde quieres mostrarlo es parte del mismo plugin, si ese plugin iría en un widget, etc. Creo que primero tienes que aclararte sobre lo que quieres.

Comment: a ver me explico mejor, tengo la web donde en un custom html he creado un formulario, del cual quiero recoger los datos del formulario y hacer una consulta a la base de datos, bien eso lo hice por un plugin que me cree el cual me hace la consulta bien, pero no me devuelve los datos de la consulta donde necesito, necesito que los datos de la consulta se visualicen en el custom html, debajo del formulario, de esa forma cuando se le de al boton me aparecera debajo el mensaje con el dato que el plugin recogio de la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Crees que necesitas un plugin para eso? Sigo pensando que te estás complicando la vida en el fondo por desconocimiento sobre como funciona Wordpress. En este caso por ejemplo puedes valerte de un `hook` simplemente o incluso de un `shortcode`
.  Quizá [este artículo](https://platzi.com/blog/hooks-wordpress/) o bien [este otro](https://www.dariobf.com/wordpress-hooks/) puedan ayudarte a aclarar algunos conceptos antes de lanzarte en querer solucionar algo con una herramienta que quizá no es la más adecuada. Yo preguntaría, ¿por qué crees que necesitas un plugin para resolver esto?

Comment: Lo que quiero saber en si es si hay una forma de ver ese dato del plugin (el cual consegi almacenar en una variable en javascript) sencilla o por el contrario tengo que hacerlo mediante Ajax como he visto. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: He pensado en un plugin básicamente para la conexión con la base de datos, fue la forma que vi mas recomendada por Internet para conectarme a la base de datos y trabajar con ella.

Comment: Noooop. Es mejor hacer eso con un `hook` o con un `shortcode` o una combinación de ambos. Incluso, para conectarte a la base de datos puedes usar PDO directamente o mysqli en vez de la conexión que ofrece Wordpress. Te diré algo, si aprendes a usar los `hooks` y los `shortcode` podrás trabajar en background con PHP puro y mostrar ese contenido en Wordpress. De hecho, tengo un sitio que funciona así y la diferencia es notable. Digamos que pones un shortcode así. `[persona id="1"]` en una página cualquiera de WP y en background lanzas una consulta que te trae los datos de la persona 1 en la BD.

Comment: Bastante interesante parece muy util la verdad, estoy mirando los articulos que me mandaste y los hooks no sabia como trabajar con ellos, los shotcode probe a usarlos pero no me dieron resultado, supongo por que los añadi en el plugin no en el archivo function.php como dice en los articulos. Muchas gracias compañero seguiré buscando información ahora que me has guiado y intentare implementarlo

Comment: aunque leyendo ahora no se como hacer que el add_action que cree se ejecute en mi custom html cuando le de al boton, pero bueno ire mirando a ver si encuentro la solucion

Comment: Después que aprendí a trabajar con `hook` y con `shortcode` me di cuenta de que un plugin sólo sería útil si quieres compartir algo con otros, haciéndolo disponible para descarga en Wordpress. Si es para resolver problemas tuyos no necesitas un plugin para eso, puedes personalizar tu sitio perfectamente sin usar un plugin. En mi sitio por ejemplo hay contenido con el mismo formato pero para días o momentos distintos. Lo único que hay en el contenido del post es un shortcode así: `[seccion id="777"]` y todo lo demás ocurre en el back-ground. Además si agrego algo nuevo se muestra solo.

Comment: Puedes buscar un buen tutorial que explique cómo usarlos (sin plugin, porque casi todos los tutoriales que hay en castellano te sugieren que instales plugin para algo que puedes hacer a mano) además aprendes más sobre cómo funciona Wordpress por dentro. Lo mejor sería que puedas leer y entender un buen tutorial en inglés y la documentación de Wordpress. No puedo decirte más porque en mi entorno tengo un framework que se llama Thesis y algunas cosas son diferentes, como el archivo donde tengo que gestionar el comportamiento de los shortcode o de los hooks.

Comment: @A.Cedano he visto este enlace [https://laprogramaciondehoy.com/crear-shortcodes-en-wordpress/] pero he intentado implementarlo en la web y no me va no me coge el shortcode me lo muestra como texto

Comment: nada olvida lo que puse añadi el shortcode el custom html, al ponerlo en un campo de texto normal me lo cogio, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo mejor fue como me indico el compañero, usar shortcodes que me mostraban los datos, me consultaban en la base de datos, y ya de paso hice que me crearan el formulario desde el php.

```php
add_shortcode( 'compDatos', 'comprobarDatos' );
function comprobarDatos(){
  $NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];
  $ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];
  global $wpdb;
  $datos = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT *
    FROM nikkiclub
    WHERE
    numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND
    Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta';
    "
    )
  );
  $mostrarDatos = '
  <div><h3>Datos del primer titular</h3></div>
  <form method="post">
  <div>Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombretutor1" value=' .
  $datos[0]->nombretutor1 .
  '> Apellidos: <input type="text" name="apellidostutor1" value=' .
  $datos[0]->apellidostutor1 .
  '>DNI: <input type="text" name="dnitutor1" value=' .
  $datos[0]->dnitutor1 .
  '></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Modificar" >
  </form>';
  return $mostrarDatos;
}
```